# Android, LayoutInflater not working

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I need your help with this Inflater. From Activity3 I need to get what inside an EditText in Activity1.

Ex: in Activity1 i write my name, email, ecc. In Activity2 I choose my birthday and in the Activity3 i want to see both.

So i used in the Activity3 the LayoutInflater, but when i parse the EditText to string, the string is empty.

Here's the code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register1, null);
    etName = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etLastName = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
    etEmail = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    actvCity = (AutoCompleteTextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.actvCity);
    etDescription = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.etDescription);

    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register2, null);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) v2.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    birthday = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    /** Register Button Click event */
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
            String lastName = etLastName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            String description = etDescription.getText().toString().trim();
            String city = actvCity.getText().toString().trim();
            String dateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(birthday.getTime());

            //if (!name.isEmpty() && !lastName.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !city.isEmpty()) 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //}

        }
    });

}
```

The dateString works. But with all the other strings are empty ("").

How can i fix this or tell me if there is another solution to this porblem.

Thanks.

Comment: you should pass the data between the activities in a bundle inside the startactivity intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout you are inflating in `Activity3` using `inflater.inflate()` is different from what you might have inflated in `Activity1` or `Activity2`.

You cannot use the data entered in different activities just by inflating the layout.
You need to use `getIntent()` in the receiving activity and set that required data in the `intent` (used in `startActivity(intent)`) on the sender activity's side.

So you need to pass your values from `Activity1` to `Activity2` first , then fetch the data in `Activity2` and then again send the combined data of `Activity1` and `Activity2` to `Activity3`.
For more details on data transfer using intents check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393287/how-should-i-communicate-between-activities).

Comment: Ok, i'll try this way. Thank you!