# How to let the user set the background color of the activity by using the edittext?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I want the user to type the color in the edit text and the background change to that color.

Comment: you should rephrase the question. which technology are you using, which controls give you that problem etc.

Comment: Send the text typed by the user to the other activity using a Bundle. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393287/how-should-i-communicate-between-activities