# add and display data in Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a problem so I have a problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtirS.png)
In the Scan Activity, QR Codes are scanned and the card data is generated, then when the value is matched, we go to the next activity where we are shown the next value. Click on the Next button and go to our list of data. Ask how to get from the ScanActivity.class Activity card data and add a list

piece of code from ScanActitivty.java

```
if (!p.matcher(decodedBarcodeValue).matches()) {
                            showAlterDialog("Błędny QR Kod", "Podany kod QR code jest błędny. Zeskanuj go ponownie.");

                        } else {

                            Matcher m = p.matcher(decodedBarcodeValue);

                            while (m.find()) {
                                daneKarty[index] = m.group(1);
                                index++;
                            }

                            if (daneKarty.length < 6) {
                                showAlterDialog("Błędny  QR Kod", "Podany Kod jest nieprawidłowy");
                            }

                            sciezka3 = daneKarty[0];
                            base32 = daneKarty[1];
                            nameCard = daneKarty[2];
                            intervalTotp = daneKarty[3];
                            passwordHotp = daneKarty[4];
                            expirationDate = daneKarty[5];

                            if (intervalTotp.equals("")) {
                                intervalTotp = "60";

                            }

                            try {
                                OTP = generateOTP(base32, uuidDevice);
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Base32 code = new Base32();
                            byte secret[] = code.decode(OTP);

                            try {
                                hotpValue = Hotp.generateHotp(secret, hotp_counter, 6);
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (hotpValue.equals(passwordHotp)) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, Stage3Activity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, hotpValue);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                            } else {
                                showAlterDialog("Błędny  QR Kod", "Podany Kod jest nieprawidłowy");
                            }
```

Stage3Activity.class

```
public class Stage3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String hotpValueString;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stage3);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_restart);

        hotpValueString = getIntent().getStringExtra("hotpValume");

        Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface custom_fonts2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

        TextView title_activity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stage3TileActivity);
        title_activity.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        TextView stageOneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageOneText);
        stageOneText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        TextView stageTwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageTwoText);
        stageTwoText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        TextView stageThreeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageThreeText);
        stageThreeText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        TextView messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        messageView.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        TextView valueHotp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueHotpTextView);
        valueHotp.setTypeface(custom_fonts2);

        valueHotp.setText(hotpValueString);

        TextView yesButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        yesButton.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Stage3Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }

    private RecyclerView cardRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

        cardRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardViewRecycleView);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        cardRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // title application
        TextView title_app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        title_app.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    }
```

class Class

```
public class Card {

    private String nameCard;
    private String dateCard;
    private String dateExpiration;

    public Card(String nameCard, String dateCard, String dateExpiration) {
        this.nameCard = nameCard;
        this.dateCard = dateCard;
        this.dateExpiration = dateExpiration;
    }

    public String getNameCard() {
        return nameCard;
    }

    public void setNameCard(String nameCard) {
        this.nameCard = nameCard;
    }

    public String getDateCard() {
        return dateCard;
    }

    public void setDateCard(String dateCard) {
        this.dateCard = dateCard;
    }

    public String getDateExpiration() {
        return dateExpiration;
    }

    public void setDateExpiration(String dateExpiration) {
        this.dateExpiration = dateExpiration;
    }
}
```

CardAdapter.class

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Card card;

    public CardAdapter( List<Card> cardsList) {
        this.cardsList = cardsList;
    }

    //dodaj obiekt do listy
    private void addItem(int position, Card card) {
        cardsList.add(position, card);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }


    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public CardView cardview;
        public TextView nameCard, dateText, setDateText, dateExpirationText, setDateExpirationText;
        public ImageView mImageButton;
        Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");


        public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //  name Card
            nameCard = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameCard);
            nameCard.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

            //data add Card
            setDateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.setDateText);
            setDateText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

            dateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            dateText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

            mImageButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.garbageDelete);

            //data expiration date
            dateExpirationText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateExpiration);
            dateExpirationText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

            //
            setDateExpirationText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.setDateExpirationText);
            setDateExpirationText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

            cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            cardview.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CardDetailsActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, parent, false);

        return new CardViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Card Card = cardsList.get(position);
        holder.nameCard.setText(Card.getNameCard());
        holder.dateText.setText(R.string.data_dodania);
        holder.setDateText.setText(Card.getDateCard());
        holder.mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.mImageButton, position);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: pass position as well while calling an Activity and get back when setResult, notify adapter using that position thats it

Answer (score -2):

If I understood correctly, and all you want is pass data between `Activities`, you can do it with `Bundles`.

Here you have the same questions answered: 
[How should I communicate between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393287/how-should-i-communicate-between-activities)

For more sophisticated data, have a look here instead: [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: on class ScanActivity.class  pull out the card data name Card , expirationDate , save do list and display list

Comment: You have to add the Card data to the `Bundle` of the `Intent` before `startActivity`. Read the links, I am not doing it for you.