# Chronometer null object reference

Tags: android, chronometer

I have a chronometer in second activity. I wanted to access it from main activity so i put the chronometer in second activity as public static and "secondActivity.chronometer" in main activity but when launching the app it shows `chronometer.setbase(long) on a null object reference` I've checked the xml id is correct. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a terrible idea for several reasons, not least of all because you are almost certainly creating a memory leak by maintaining a static reference to a `View` (your `Chronometer`). Use an `Intent` or event bus or some other mechanism for communicating between your two Activities (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393287/how-should-i-communicate-between-activities)

Comment: cause i'm actually wanted to let my chronometer running in background when launching main activity using ```Service``` does it also have to use ```Intent``` to access the chronometer? won't it affect the ```Service```?

Comment: By "in the background", I take it you mean it isn't visible? In that case, it doesn't need to be running - you just need to store the "start time" of your chronometer somewhere and then, when your chronometer *is* visible, call `Chronometer#setBase` using the time, and it will update to the correct difference between then and now. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: So I have to remove ```Intent``` as it just directly start the second activity instead of making it running in background which isn't visible?

Comment: Sure, you can invoke the `Intent` whenever you're ready to show the chronometer. Otherwise, you only need to store that "start time" somewhere. It could be in memory, or you can write it to `SharedPreferences` or something.

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialized the chronometer.
when you launch the app , chronometer don't have any value because it is in second activity .

Answer (score 0):

When you launching the app, the second activity is not initialized. The chronometer , as a TextView's subclass, also cannot be initialized. It is not a good idea to access or change a view in other activity. You can transfer data and show by the data。

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, retaining a static reference to a `View` is a very bad idea. First, as other answers have made clear, there is not guarantee that your `View` will have been initialised when you call it, as the `Activity` it is part of may have not yet initialised. However, it also a prime cause of memory leaks (see [this answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks)).

My recommendation would be that instead of starting your `Chronometer`, instead make a note of the time you *want* it to start (which, in the case of `Chronometer`, can be obtained by calling `SystemClock#uptimeMillis`), writing it to an `Intent`, and using that to launch your second `Activity`. You can then use this time as the base time for your `Chronometer`, and therefore give the impression that it has been running the entire time. I.e.

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
    //...
    private void startChronometer() {
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        i.putExtra("time", SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

    private Chronometer chrono;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        chrono = findViewById(R.id.id_of_chronometer);
        chrono.setBase(getIntent().getLongExtra("time", SystemClock.uptimeMillis()));
        chrono.start();
    }

}
```